# Comparison between FlexRule and Express IT - BRE

Tags: .net

Can anyone provide me comparison between FlexRule and Express IT - BRE. 
And which is better for implementation and why

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for our late response. The big difference is that FlexRule is Process engine (including generic flow and workflow), Data engine and Rules engine(supporting multi-level decisions and rules). This combination is critical for model systems.

When complexity and volume of your rules grow, if you only try to design from rules perspective you will hit a problem called "a big bucket of rules" problem. That means you have now too many rules with no clue on reusability, traceability across different scenarios (and potentially multiple processes). This is why you would be worries more about rules conflict and their resolution.

Let's describe the issue and solution in more details. To address this challenge, you need to look at rules from decision perspective. Group your rules into collections that they answer the question of decision (e.g. how much discount a customer is eligible for?). Then start decompose this big decisions based on smaller ones and define the relation between your decisions (e.g. seasonal discount and quantity discount). This will look like a dependency diagram but for decisions. It is called Decision Requirement Diagram (DRD).

In our example then the discount eligibility depends on two other sub-decisions: quantity and seasonal discount decisions.

Now you have a high-level model without worrying about rules too much so it is time to drill down and start implementing the rules for each decision. Each decision can have multiple different rules. But their relation are isolated inside their own decision.

This is an example of what I described here: http://www.flexrule.com/archives/decision-model-and-notation-policy-example/

This modern approach of modeling rules is a MUST if you need to have a scalable system that is based on rules. That's why in FlexRule we not only allow you to use the BRE only (like traditional approach on rules) but also, encourage you to approach rules in a modern way (decision approach).

I hope this concept information is useful and describes how FlexRule is different in the market.

Disclaimer: I work for FlexRule.